# Why does the compiler allow initializing a variable with itself?

Tags: c

I finally trace down a typo bug, which is something similar to the following code.
But shouldn't the compiler detect this (by default options)?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c = c;
    return printf("%d\n", c);
}


$ gcc --version        
gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3
```

Comment: You invoke undefined behaviour with the initialization; the compiler is not require to diagnose the problem, or to define what it does when it encounters it.

Comment: I'd bet my left shoe that when you turn on warnings (-Wall in GCC), it will warn you when you're doing this. Try not to ignore warnings ;-)

Comment: I used GCC 4.7.1 with compiler options: `gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -c x.c` and the complaints were about 'not a prototype' and 'old-style function definition' and not about the variable initialization.  
OTOH, `clang` diagnosed: `x.c:5:13: warning: variable 'c' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]` (but adding `-Wuninitialized` to the GCC options didn't add to the messages — `clang` has better diagnostics here).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, good point. I assumed that this is really something GCC should point out, but I assume it thinks that `c` is initialized (with `c` :-) )

Comment: gcc has a `-Winit-self` flag.

Comment: @nothrow give me your shoe, `-Wall -Wextra` does not include `-Winit-self` in GCC 4.9.3.

Comment: Also see [C++ version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see why it wouldn't compile. Definition happens prior to initialization. Of course this initialization is pointless, however, there's no reason it wouldn't work from the compilers stand point.

C does not have the same types of protections that more modern languages like C# have. The C# compiler would give an error that you're using an unassigned variable. C doesn't care. It will not protect you from yourself.

Comment: This initialization, not assignment.

Comment: Also, being able to refer to the variable for its initialization is *useful*, because you can take its address, as in `int x = initialize_and_register(&x)`. (That kind of invocation would typically be packaged in a macro.)

Comment: @user4815162342 true, that obviously makes sense. I should have chosen my words better :(

Comment: Your words are quite fine (except for the distinction between initialization and assignment), I was just offering a suggestion for a further improvement of the answer. Your answer doesn't make it clear that there are cases where using `x` in an expression initializing `x` is actually useful, so it's not (only) about C not protecting you from yourself. And if you wish to add that info to the answer, that's what the "Edit" button is for. :)

Comment: That's why C "warnings" exist : they don't trigger an error, but merely warn the programmer about a suspicious pattern.

Answer (score 5):

It's perfectly legitimate to use a variable in its own initializer.  Consider a linked list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct node { struct node *prev, *next; int value; };
int main() {
    struct node l[] = {{0, l + 1, 42}, {l, l + 2, 5}, {l, 0, 99}};
    for (struct node *n = l; n; n = n->next)
        printf("%d\n", n->value);
    return 0;
}
```

In general, diagnosing when a value is used uninitialised is a difficult problem; although some compilers can detect it in some cases it doesn't make sense to require it to happen.

Comment: How is undefined behavior legitimate?

Comment: This isn't quite initializing a variable with itself, but rather a pointer to itself, since `l` decays into a pointer `&[0]` in this context.

Comment: @this in this particular case (array-to-pointer decay), yes. In most cases it would not be.